# Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I trying to builg app with a table view and I can't find a solution for this error:

> "Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers"

The video for this tutorial use the Swift a last version and I can't find where I can make it.

[image]

Both ways are not working.

I tried finding a solution here, on FaceBook, on YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is present in the attribute inspector, please check the attached screenshot for the reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reuse identifier is in the Attribute Inspector (the inspector with the [image] symbol),
`Identifier` is the third field from above.

It's not the Restoration ID nor the Accessibility Identifier.